# How to find a continuous path between matrices?

Tags: lie-groups, path-connected

> I have matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$ and matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\0&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\end{pmatrix}$ and I want to find a continuous path between them. How do I do this?

I know that matrices in $SO(n)$ should be path connected but how do you actually construct such a path?

I'm not sure if just taking $\gamma(t)=A(t)+B(1-t)$ is going to work.

Comment: Do you need a path in $SO(n)$ or just any path?

Comment: I think there is a minus-sign missing in matrix $A$, not it is not in $SO(3)$ as it has determinant $-1$

Comment: But if both matrices are written correctly, this greatly illustrates @ArcticChar's point: As $A$ has determinant $-1$ and $B$ has determinant $1$, obviously the path must somewhere pass through a matrix with determinant zero. (If you only allow real matrices, that is.) So if you want your path to stay within $SO(3)$ (or even $GL(3)$) no such path exist, while if you allow all matrices this is not a problem and your $\gamma$ would do the trick.

Comment: Geometrically, all elements of $SO(3)$ are rotations about a line. To obtain a path within $SO(3)$, you can e.g. first move the rotation axis from one to the other, then move the angle.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, I missed the negative.

Comment: @Berci So I know that $A$ fixes the z-axis and $B$ fixes the x-axis. So I should take a rotation about y-axis to move the z-axis? I'm not sure how to make this into a path though.

Comment: Think about an orthonormal basis is moved together, the basis should contain the eigenvector of the axis. Yes, in this example you rotate them about the y-axis, continuously.

Comment: @Berci I'm still not sure how I make that into a path though. I can get a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$ that will move the first column vector of $A$ to the first of $B$. But I dont really know how I move the whole matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check that any two dimensional rotation matrix can be written as $$R_\theta = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix} = e^{\theta J} \quad \text{where} \quad J = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Using this fact, we have $$R_{\pi/2} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} = e^{(\pi/2)J} \quad \text{and} \quad R_{\pi/3} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} = e^{(\pi/3)J}.$$

Block-diagonal matrices $M = \begin{bmatrix}M_1 & 0 \\ 0 & M_2\end{bmatrix}$ satisfy $e^M = \begin{bmatrix}e^{M_1} &  \\  & e^{M_2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore, $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = e^{C} \quad \text{where} \quad C = \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{\pi}{2}J & \\ & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$ and $$B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & -\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 & \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} = e^{D} \quad \text{where} \quad D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \\ & \tfrac{\pi}{3}J \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{\pi}{3}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Finally, you can check that for any anti-symmetric real matrix $H$, $e^H$ is in $SO(n)$. Can you use these facts to connect $A = e^C$ to $B = e^D$ by a continuous path in $SO(3)$? You have the right idea to use something like $t \cdot (\text{start point}) + (1-t) \cdot (\text{end point})$, but you need to tie in the matrix exponential somehow to guarantee the path stays in $SO(3)$.

Comment: I sort of think it would be $e^{Ct+(1-t)D}$ because multiplying the anti-symmetric matrix by a scalar shouldn't make it not scalar anymore.

Comment: The product of an anti-symmetric matrix and a scalar is another anti-symmetric matrix. Why do you think that is bad?

Comment: No I'm saying that $tC$ and $(1-t)D$ will always be anti symmetric but I don't know that their sum will be anti-symmetric.

Comment: The sum of two anti-symmetric matrices is also anti-symmetric. Can you try to prove it?

Comment: Ok yeah I see why. So this function should work then? Can you link me to a proof that $e^X$ is always in $SO(n)$ if $X$ is anti-symmetric?

Comment: If $X$ is anti-symmetric, then $e^X(e^{X})^T = e^Xe^{X^T} = e^Xe^{-X} = e^{X-X} = e^{0} = I$, where the step $e^Xe^{-X} = e^{X-X}$ follows since $X$ and $-X$ commute. Similarly, $(e^{X})^Te^X = I$. Thus, $e^X \in SO(n)$.

Comment: Does this only work for block diagonal matrices? Because for example you can have matrices which are in $SO(n)$ like $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\M&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ Which Im not sure work this way.

Comment: For any two matrices $A,B \in SO(n)$ you can form a continuous path between them using $e^{t\log A + (1-t)\log B}$. However, for some matrices in $SO(n)$, you might have a harder time computing the matrix logarithm.

Comment: What I wanted to do was define a path like this $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\cos(\theta(1-t))&-\sin(\theta(1-t))\\0&\sin(\theta(1-t))&\cos(\theta(1-t))\\\end{pmatrix}$ so I can get a path to the identity whenever I have a block diagonal matrix. And then just put the 2 paths together, but this won't work if I have a matrix which isn't block diagonal. For example $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\\cos(0)&-\sin(0)&0\\\sin(0)&\cos(0)&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ I don't see how I get to the identity with a matrix of this form. Since the $SO(2)$ matrix isn't on the diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't any element in $\text{SO}(n)$ have an exponential representation? 
I.e for any $U \in \text{SO}$, there is a matrix $H$ such that:
$U= e^{H} $  
If this is true, the connecting  path is apparent, isn't it?
**Disclaimer**: I'm not expert in algebra or geometry.

Comment: Its not really apparent to me, how would you find $H$?

Comment: I'm not sure. Does diagonalization help? It is quite clear to me. But maybe I am wrong. Btw, I overstated the "skew" part, that part was meant for unitary matrix.

Comment: It seems there is still something with the connection of eigenvalues, and maybe we need some modifications with the statement. But my intuition tells me, they are all feasible.  And if there are more problems, I give up. I haven't touched any serious questions on algebra for along time.

Comment: Indeed, $A = e^C$ where $C = \dfrac{\pi}{2}\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = e^D$ where  $D =  \dfrac{\pi}{3}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$. I found that using MATLAB's logm function, but I'm sure there is an analytic way to figure that out. It's been about 8 years since I've had to work with $SO(3)$.